# Warning/Error : "Found x elements with non-unique id" REACTJS API REST

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, api, input

I want to do a form with the values corresponding of each book (with the id which is associate to), but the console write this warning "Found x(number of books) elements with non-unique id". So, it's written the informations of the same book everywhere, because the id isn't recognized. What can I change/add in my code please? 
Here is my return:

```
return (
    <div>
      <MDBTable hover>
        <MDBTableHead>
          <tr>
            <th>Titre</th>
            <th>Auteur</th>
            <th>Année de sortie</th>
            <th>Edition</th>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Statut</th>
            <th>Date d'achat</th>
            <th></th>
          </tr>
        </MDBTableHead>
        <MDBTableBody>
          {
            this.state.books.map(livre => (
              <tr key={livre.id} onChange={this.Change} >
                <td>{livre.title} </td>
                <td>{livre.author}</td>
                <td>{livre.year}</td>
                <td>{livre.edition}</td>
                <td>{livre.typeBook}</td>
                <td>{livre.status}</td>
                <td>{livre.date}</td>
                <td><MDBBtn color="dark" onClick={this.toggle(8)}>Edit</MDBBtn>
                      <MDBModal isOpen={this.state.modal8} toggle={this.toggle(8)} fullHeight position="top">
                        <MDBModalHeader toggle={this.toggle(8)}>{livre.title}</MDBModalHeader>
                        <MDBModalBody>
                        <div className="grey-text">
                    <label htmlFor="title" className="grey-text">
                      Titre
                    </label>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      id="title"
                      placeholder={livre.title}
                      className="form-control"
                      onChange={this.change}
                    />

                    <br />

                    <label htmlFor="author" className="grey-text">
                      Auteur
                    </label>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      id="author"
                      placeholder={livre.author}
                      className="form-control"
                      onChange={this.change}
                    />

                    <br />

                    <label htmlFor="year" className="grey-text">
                      Année de sortie
                    </label>
                    <input
                      type="number"
                      id="year"
                      className={"form-control"}
                      placeholder={livre.year}
                      onChange={this.change}
                    />

                    <br />

                    <label htmlFor="date" className="grey-text">
                      Date d&apos;achat
                    </label>
                    <input
                      type="date"
                      id="date"
                      placeholder={livre.date}
                      className="form-control"
                      onChange={this.change}
                    />

                    <br />

                    <label htmlFor="edition" className="grey-text">
                      Edition
                    </label>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      id="edition"
                      placeholder={livre.edition}
                      className="form-control"
                      onChange={this.change}
                    />

                    <br />

                    <label htmlFor="typeBook" className="grey-text">
                      Type
                    </label>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      id="typeBook"
                      placeholder={livre.typeBook}
                      className="form-control"
                      onChange={this.change}
                    />

                    <br />

                    <label htmlFor="status" className="grey-text">
                      Statut
                    </label>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      id="status"
                      placeholder={livre.status}
                      className="form-control"
                      onChange={this.change}
                    />


                  </div>
                        </MDBModalBody>
                        <MDBModalFooter>
                          <MDBBtn color="danger" onClick={this.toggle(8)}>Annuler</MDBBtn>
                          <MDBBtn color="dark">Enregistrer</MDBBtn>
                        </MDBModalFooter>
                      </MDBModal>               
                </td>

              </tr>
            ))
          }
        </MDBTableBody>
      </MDBTable>

    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `map` you're creating elements with `id`s on them. You should be making those `id`s unique somehow. Where ever an element is given an `id`, that `id` must be unique or you'll have problems with apis that rely on them.

Open find, type in `id="` and you should be able to see them. Since they're in a `map`, for every element of the array you're generating an element with the same id.

It's probably as easy as appending the index to the id or just omitting it unless you have a specific use for it.

Comment: I have a different id for each book in each row, and when I press the edit button, I want the details of the book affected with this id. I don't understand what I can change to get this result?

Comment: Google HTML id. It's a property on html elements. In you map above you have it on several JSX properties that will pass to the DOM

Comment: `<input type="text" id="status"... >` I done such instance inside your map. Those are eventually HTML id properties and are causing your problem.

Comment: Ah ok I understand, thank you. But the id in the input like this are present because I want to edit the value of the status for example, so how can I do in order to not put 2 difference id?

Comment: Use a different property and look for that on the events triggering element. Say like use the `name` property and use that instead of `id` in the change handler